# How do I manage a mix of menu and custom breadcrumbs?

Tags: 8, navigation, breadcrumbs

I have a site where I need breadcrumbs to be generated in a couple of different ways:

- Based on the menu path (Menu Breadcrumb)
- Based on custom rules (was thinking Custom Breadcrumb but it doesnt exist anymore)

How can I effectively enable breadcrumb rules for nodes that I *don't* want Menu Breadcrumb to control? Do I have to create my own Breadcrumb builder class? Can I blow away `$breadcrumb` in `hook_system_breadcrumb_alter` and do `new Breadcrumb()` to do exactly what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to create my own Breadcrumb builder class?

Yes, there are many places where you can modify breadcrumbs, but this is the only straightforward way. The custom breadcrumbs should have a priority higher than 1010 (the priority of the breadcrumb builder of Menu Breadcrumbs), so that nodes that follow rules you put in `applies()` of the BreadCrumbBuilder class can't be controlled by Menu Breadcrumbs.

> How do I set the priority (asked in the comments)?

The priority is set in the service definition, example from the Menu Breadcrumb module:

*menu_breadcrumb.services.yml:*

```
services:
  menu_breadcrumb.breadcrumb.default:
    class: Drupal\menu_breadcrumb\MenuBasedBreadcrumbBuilder
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@menu.active_trail', '@plugin.manager.menu.link', '@router.admin_context', '@title_resolver', '@request_stack', '@language_manager', '@entity_type.manager']
    tags:
      # The priority must be higher than core taxonomy builder (priority: 1002)
      # see https://www.drupal.org/node/1495510
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 1010 }
```

(which is also where you have to look when you want to override an existing breadcrumb builder, you can see here what was considered concerning the taxonomy breadcrumbs)